# Fatal error: Class 'finfo' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\portfolio\actions\addProject_action.php on line 49

Tags: php

I'm trying to do a fileupload on my website. And I checked in the PHP manual and found this for checking the filetype:

```
// DO NOT TRUST $_FILES['upfile']['mime'] VALUE !!
// Check MIME Type by yourself.
$finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE); // line 49
if (false === $ext = array_search(
    $finfo->file($_FILES['topImage']['tmp_name']),
    array(
        'jpg' => 'image/jpeg',
        'png' => 'image/png',
        'gif' => 'image/gif',
    ),
    true
)) {
    throw new RuntimeException('Invalid file format.');
}
```

But with this code I get an php error that says: 
Fatal error: Class 'finfo' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\portfolio\actions\addProject_action.php on line 49

Anyone that know why and how to fix this? (apparently I have the wrong PHP version 5.2.0, so I would more like to know if there is a similar good way to do this in erlier PHP versions?)

I have this code inside this:

```
if(empty($_FILES['topImage'])){
    $errors['topImage'] = "You have to choose a Top Image.";
}else{
    // The code is inside here
}
```

Comment: it states that no where any class with the name  `finfo` exists in your current working directory.thanks.

Comment: Yes I got that, but why? And how do I fix it? They dont explain anything about that part so I thought it just was code to use

Comment: The example is from: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Comment: You haven wrote a link? The link I wrote is the one that I followed. It dosen't say anything about how to fix this or that this even is a possibility?

Comment: sorry. my mistake. really sorry

Comment: @SannaBergström What is your `echo phpversion();` ?

Comment: It seems like I have 5.2.0.. So I might more want the answer how to do this diffrently :/. Atleast it says so in xampp.. Cant get it out otherwise, think I did something some time ago to not be able to write out the information.. Don't remember how and dont have the time now to undo it :P.

Answer (score 2):

i think finfo class is available in PHP >= 5.3.0. maybe your PHP is lower 5.3.0.

Comment: Ok, defently gonna check. if it is, is there another way to do this?

Comment: Take look at this [Link](http://php.net/manual/en/book.fileinfo.php) for more infos

Comment: But I still just have PHP 5.2.0, so need to find another way

Comment: Do you found it ? If not, i hope this link is help you to validate image http://www.bitrepository.com/how-to-validate-an-image-upload.html

Answer (score 2):

uncomment the line `;extension=php_fileinfo.dll` in the file \xampp\php\php.ini

Comment: It should be a comment than an anwer